# what does it. mean in the context of alos operator

Tags: android, kotlin, scoping

I am learning how to use the coroutines in kotlin. looking at some examples in the internet i found that within the context f the also operator the reference

```
it
```

is used. i could not find any explanation about the meaning of

```
it
```

please provide some brief explanantion about what does "it" mean

Comment: Did you check the docs? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter

Answer (score 0):

`it` is the [implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)
For more information about it and this in scoping functions like [`also`](http://%20https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#context-object-this-or-it)

Answer (score 0):

when you use the `also` method, it has 1 parameter.

Think of it in Java kinda like this:

```
foo.also(int it) { 
   // do stuff
}
```

In Kotlin, the `it` parameter is implicit (sometimes you might want to use it sometimes you don't).

If you want to rename `it` to something more readable you can

```
foo.also { newName -> 
  // do stuff with newName
}
```

Or just use it like it is

```
foo.also {
  // do stuff with $it
}
```

So therefore when you are using a method (or a closure/lambda) if it has 1 parameter, then the implicit name of that parameter is always `it`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `it` represents the lambda parameter

let's say you want to perform anything on the variable but do to check the nullity first, you can do it like

```
var str:String?=null // str is of string type
```

now you can use it  fail safe

```
str?.let{it:String// youll see like this
   // now you can access str as **it**

}
```